# How to retrieve multiple data (rows) from database SQLite Java

Tags: java, android, sqlite, mobile-application

This is what I have done right now.

My table is like this:

```
JAPANESEALPHA            ENGLISH          JAPANESECHAR
kiro                     kilo            \u30ad\u30ed
guramu                   gram            \u30b0\u30e9\u30e0
migi                     right           \u307f\u304e
mijikai                  short           \u307f\u3058\u304b\u3044
```

Inside database (example):

```
mDbHelper.createCrv("kiro","kilo","\u30ad\u30ed");
mDbHelper.createCrv("guramu","gram","\u30b0\u30e9\u30e0");
mDbHelper.createCrv("mijikai","short","\u307f\u3058\u304b\u3044");
mDbHelper.createCrv("minami","south","\u307f\u306a\u307f");
mDbHelper.createCrv("miru","watch","\u307f\u308b");
```

Query:

```
 String query = "SELECT docid as _id," + 
    KEY_ENGLISH + "," +
    KEY_JAPANESEALPHA + "," +
    KEY_JAPANESECHAR+ 
    " from " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE +
    " where " +  KEY_JAPANESEALPHA + " = '" + inputText + "';";
```

I also have Cursor:

```
 private void showResults(String query) {

        Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.searchCrvJapanesechar((query != null ? query.toString() : "@@@@"));
        if (cursor == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "No Search Found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {

            // Specify the columns we want to display in the result 
            String[] from = new String[] {
                    DBAdapter.KEY_JAPANESECHAR,
                   DBAdapter.KEY_JAPANESEALPHA,
                   DBAdapter.KEY_ENGLISH
                   };
                    //DBAdapter.KEY_TAGALOG};


            // Specify the Corresponding layout elements where we want the columns to go
            int[] to = new int[] {     R.id.sjapanesechar,
                   R.id.sjapanesealpha,
                    R.id.senglish};
                   // R.id.stagalog};
```

For compound words, I need to minimize my database so that when the

```
Input: kiroguramu
```

I can concatenate the english term of kiru and english term of guramu. That will result

```
Result: kilogram
```

Sorry I can't paste my sample images because I'm newbie. 
I have get the retrieving data at http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/11/android-searchview-using-sqlite-fts3.html It was a great help.
Thankyou.

Comment: i did'nt get your question........tell me what's your input and what you want as output............

Comment: try explain your question more clearly, and post your table structure

Comment: Use a Cursor? Just go through this, will help you lot http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html

Comment: you can check this source code download it and worke like it. i think you new in android you need to learn basic tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/

Comment: Thanks you. Please if you have better algorithm for this, please let me know.

Comment: Actually, I have get the retrieving of data code at this site http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/11/android-searchview-using-sqlite-fts3.html But only single row data can retrieve. Please response. Thanks

Comment: @NidhishKrishnan I have  edited my question, sorry for my english, not my native language.

Comment: what does this ........String query = "SELECT docid as _id," + 
    KEY_ENGLISH + "," +
    KEY_JAPANESEALPHA + "," +
    KEY_JAPANESECHAR+ 
    " from " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE +
    " where " +  KEY_JAPANESEALPHA + " = '" + inputText + "';";.....................tells, from which table it is retrieving all these

Comment: The query tells that when the inputText matched the japanesealpha(column) it will retrieved the english term from the database. Is it possible that the inputText is composed of two words (both inside the database) that will retrieve the two different english terms? and that concatenated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I think you should try to read some basic of JSON parsing here
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/